# How to stream archive to S3 by parts in lambda function?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have stored a lot of a user's files on my Amazon S3 storage. I have to provide all these files to the user by request.

For this purpose, I have implemented the lambda function that collects path to user's files, creates a zip archive and store back this archive on s3. Where a user could download it.

My code looks like:

```
using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client()){
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()){
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)){
            foreach (var file in m_filePathsOnS3){
                var response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(m_sourceBucket, file);
                var name = file.Split('/').Last();
                ZipArchiveEntry entry = zip.CreateEntry(name);

                using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open()){
                    await response.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                }
            }
        }

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest{
            BucketName = m_resultBucket,
            Key = m_archivePath,
            InputStream = memoryStream
        };

        await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);        
    }
}
```

But, lambda function has [the limitation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) in 3008 MB max memory allocation. So if I understand correctly, I will have the issue when trying to make the archive more than 3008 MB.
I looked for a way to stream and archive files on the fly.
Currently, I see only one way - move this lambda function to EC2 instance as service.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. There is also a limit of 500MB of disk space, which would impact this.

Therefore, AWS Lambda is not a good use-case for creating potentially very large zip files.